# iOS: "Message sent to deallocated instance" when resign first responder on a UITextView when its auto correction pop-up is shown

Tags: ios, uitextview, dealloc, resignfirstresponder, autocorrect

I have a custom toolbar with a "Done" button for the input accessary view of my text view. When this "Done" button is tapped I want to resign the text view from the first responder, so I call:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

This will throw an error:

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
```

when the "Done" button is tapped while the auto correction is shown (See image below). The error still even I call:

```
if ([textView isFirstResponder] && [textView canResignFirstResponder]) [textView resignFirstResponder];
```

It seems like the text view is the first responder and can be resigned but I cannot resign it. How can I solve this error? Thank you.

Edit 1: I still want to enable auto correction.

Edit 2: Please take a look at the capture image below.

[image: auto correction is shown]

Edit 3: After turning on `Zombies` in the scheme settings, the logged message is:

```
-[TIZephyrCandidate wordOriginFeedbackID]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x52bbc50
```

but I don't know what is the meaning of this message and what to do next.

Edit 4: The method to resign first responder will be called when the "Done" button is touched up inside the button is added target and action by the following line of code:

```
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(resignAllFirstResponders) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which the `resignAllFirstResponders` is:

```
- (void)resignAllFirstResponders
{
    ...

    if ([textView canResignFirstResponder] && [textView isFirstResponder]) 
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Turn on Zombies in the Xcode 4 scheme settings. Replicate the crash and inspect which released object being messaged is raising the exception.

Comment: @MarkAdams I went to **Xcode -> Product -> Edit Scheme...** and checked the box in front of **Enable Zombie Objects**. Is this what you mean by "Turn on Zombies in the Xcode 4 scheme settings"? If so, please take a look log message in my edited question again. Thanks.

Comment: Ok so we know that we tried to send the `wordOriginFeedbackID` message to an instance of `TIZephyrCandidate` that's already been released. Now we try to find out why resigning with the autocorrect popup visible is causing this. Where is this method called in relation to the text view?

Comment: Hold the phone. Just noticed that thread 1 is crashing. Are you trying to resign first responder from a background thread? UI objects can only be accessed on the main thread. Might explain this madness.

Comment: @MarkAdams Please take a look at my edited question again for the way I call the method. For the issue regarding the thread please suggest me how to check whether the method is called on background thread or main thread. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you would know if you were using a background thread. We need to find out what `TIZephyrCandidate` is and why it's being sent `wordOriginFeedbackID` in response to the text view giving up first responder status. Do you have the `UITextViewDelegate` method, `-textViewDidEndEditing:` implemented?

Comment: No, I don't have `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` implemented but there are other text view delegates which are `- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView`, `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`, and `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. Anyway please note that I'm not sure this is a good enough solution but I just want to share my current progress and still waiting for better solution.

The concept is to find out whether subviews of the text view contains a view of `UIAutocorrectInlinePrompt` which is the auto correction pop-up that cause the error or not. Then call the method `resignFirstResponder` only when the set of subviews not contain `UIAutocorrectInlinePrompt`. My code are like this:

```
NSMutableString *subviewMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[subviewMutableString setString:@""];
for (UIView *subview in textView.subviews)
{
    [subviewMutableString appendFormat:@"%@", subview];
}
if ([subviewMutableString rangeOfString:@"UIAutocorrectInlinePrompt"].location == NSNotFound)
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This will not allow to resign text view from first responder when the auto correction pop-up is shown.

Answer (score 2):

if you using :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText
```

`UITextViewDelegate` and change directly text in the method like :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText
{
 aTextView.text = @"hi";

 return YES;
}
```

is caused crash.

1. spellchecking view was appeared,
2. resignFirstResponder of `UITextView`,
3. change text directly `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText` delegate,

app will be crashed.